# MySQL FULLTEXT not matching string with wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, myisam, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to do a basic full text search on my MySQL database - here's the table I'm using:

**tables removed**

Any input would be appreciated, as I've not used full text searching before (or indexing for that matter!)

Thanks

EDIT:

I've chosen to use `FULLTEXT` because of the supposed slowness of `LIKE` searches - there will be a whole lot of these running, as it's for a javascript autocomplete type thing. Is using `LIKE` is a viable option for this? I have been advised against it. (I bring this up because all of the answers have said to use `LIKE` rather than addressing my actual question)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Full text search has limited functionality and relatively slow search. I would suggest to use external full-text search engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) for this type of queries. I'm not familiar with Solr, but in case of Sphinx you could hire prefix indexing that supported along with enable_star option in config file.

Here is an example on [how to replace MySQL FT with Sphinx](http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/). You could also use Sphinx for faceted search, related document search and other useful stuff.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIKE` command and use the percent symbol ( `%` ) as the wildcard:

```
SELECT user_id, username, first_name, last_name 
FROM users 
WHERE (username LIKE 'Sav%') 
   OR (email LIKE 'Sav%') 
   OR (first_name LIKE 'Sav%') 
   OR (last_name LIKE 'Sav%');
```

Comment: I've chosen to use fulltext because of the supposed slowness of `like` searches - there will be a whole lot of these running, as it's for a javascript autocomplete type thing. Do you think using `like` is a viable option for this? I have been advised against it.

Comment: Add a mysql index to each column that will be searched. That should help. I have used `like` searches for autocomplete in small-scale situations without issue.

Comment: Problem is that you can't actually create index in MySQL that will efficiently handle multi-column "LIKE" queries. It is limitation of B-Tree indexes that MySQL uses internally for these indexes. They could handle only one range in queries like a = 5 and b = 'somestring' and c LIKE 'Sav%'. Which means that only one LIKE with wildcard could be covered by index, other will be filtered on one-by-one basis. You could see that in EXPLAIN output

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your metaphors here.  You want to use FULLTEXT for good reasons, then you use the syntax from LIKE.

Try searching for just plain "savo" without the wildcards, and see if that is acceptable.

BTW 2 big gotchas with Mysql FULLTEXT search:

1. It won't react to less than 4 letters being entered without going back and messing with the cnf ( I think its 4, you'd need to check on this )
2. If the result set count is greater than 50% of the number of total rows available, then it figures the search has failed, and returns nothing.  Worth remembering when only testing vs 12 rows, and say they all have the word `test` in them.  Ouch ;)

Comment: Minimal word length is controlled by ft_min_word_len option in MySQL config file and can be adjusted as needed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
 select * from users where (
username like ('Sav%') 
or email like ('Sav%') 
or first_name like ('Sav%') 
or last_name like ('Sav%') );
```